# Javascript's void in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there something like Javascript's `void` operator in C#?
Javascript's [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/void), "evaluates an expression and discards the result, returning `undefined`". Thus, I'm looking for something built-in that "evaluates" and returns `null`, or maybe the type default. (So it should sort of be like the inverse of the null-coalescing `??` operator.)

Example use:

```
Person a;

public void main() {
    var x = void(a = new Person());
    // x should contain null
}

class Person { }
```

(Example does not compile due to illegitimate use of keyword "void", naturally.)

I currently use this—which works—but feels crufty:

```
protected object voided(object ob) {
    return null;
}
```

---

Edit. Ok, so I definitely need to add some more details. I'm using the code in an inline DataBind expression in ASP.NET code. E.g.:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
       </tr><%# voided(globalPersonVariable = (Person)Container.DataItem)) %></tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Using `default`, unfortunately does not work here.
(I didn't include this additional information the first time, because I wanted to keep it a "pure" C#-question, not ASP.NET.)

Comment: Why do you need it? Put it in a context. I see no point at all writing the code like that.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `return null`. And it's not the same as void in C#.

Comment: By the way, in JavaScript, `void` is an operator, like `typeof`, not a real function. @Thai: That is pseudo-C#, not JavaScript.

Comment: It reminds me of an anonymous function the captures a variable, set it's value and and compiler infers the type of `x` in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just make an extension method, Voided()

```
public static object Voided<TType>(this TType tThis)
{
    return null;
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
(globalPersonVariable = (Person)Container.DataItem)).Voided()
```

If you want to combine this with the default stuff other people have mentioned, it would change to:

```
public static TType Voided<TType>(this TType tThis)
{
    return default(TType);
}
```

Comment: Still not exactly what I was looking for, but I quite like this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this you're looking for?

```
var x = default(Person) // null
var i = default(int) // 0
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. See the question edits why.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what `void` function does in javascript, but to get a default value of a type, use `default` keyword:

```
protected T voided<T>(T obj) {
    return default(T);
}
```

Comment: The `void` operator in JavaScript simply evaluates an expression and discards the result, returning `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But, if that's the case, why did OP try to store result of that `var x = void(a = new Person());`?

Comment: I tried to store it in `x` to reiterate the point that it needs to return "something", null preferably.

Comment: Have you looked into using `Expressions`/`Lambda`/`Delegates` as a parameter in your function? That method runs the given delegate and returns null. Not sure whether it will work with ASP.NET scriptlets but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `default` keyword:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just want to throw these two snippets into the mix.
Both work, but they still feel more verbose than necessary.

```
(globalPersonVariable = (Person)(Container.DataItem)) == null ? null : null

((Func<object,object>)(x => null))(globalPersonVariable = (Person)(Container.DataItem))
```

For databinding purposes, you can also emit the empty string:

```
(globalPersonVariable = (Person)(Container.DataItem)) == null ? "" : ""
```

The distinction might seem trivial, but this can save you from needing to cast 
the nulls in certain situations.